# How use my own function in Linq query?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq, filter

I want to take some elements by checking them with my custom function.

I have Person table:

```
public class Person
{
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public DateTime BirthDay { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        ...
}
```

I should to use my `GetAge()` **and other functions** to filter Persons list.
My following code doesnt work:

```
public List<Person> FilterPersons(int ageFrom, int ageTo...etc..) 
{
    var all = Database.Persons.AsQueryable(); 

    all = from item in all
          where GetAge(item.BirthDay) > ageFrom
          select item;

    all = from item in all
          where GetAge(item.BirthDay) < ageTo
          select item;

    // other operations
    ...
}
```

I think I can write so. In every step to do this:

```
List<Person> newList = new List<Person>();
foreach (var item in all)
{
   var itemAge = Common.GetAge(item.BirthDay);
   if (itemAge > AgeFrom)
   {
       newList.Add(item);
   }
}
all = newList.List();
```

But this is not best way I think, because I should do filter by many criteries. It will work with low speed.

How can I use my functions in Linq query?

**Edit:**
I showed GetAge() function for example. I have many functions like that. I wanted to know how to use my function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, you can't.

If you want to have criteria used in Where clause of your SQL query, you need to write them directly as a linq.Expression so that entity may parse it and transform it into SQL, not an external function.

Somthing like this works :

```
DateTime date = DateTime.Now.AddDays(ageFrom);
all = from item in all
      where item.BirthDay > date
      select item;
```

Comment: So, I can not use my function. yes? Because, I have some other functions to filter Persons, not only GetAge(). thanks for help.

Answer (score 0):

[Query Expressions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/bb397676.aspx) are built in to the C# compiler and as such, it only understands the expression that are built in to the compiler.

For example, when you use the `where` keyword, it converts that to a call to the [`Where<TSource>(this IQueryable<TSource> source, Func<TSource, bool> predicate)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb535040.aspx) method.

This is true of Linq To Objects and Linq To SQL. What's more, with Linq To SQL, the compiler then has to convert the Query Expression to SQL, which has no way of knowing the definition of your `GetAge` method.

Answer (score 0):

Or you can use this syntax:

```
DateTime date = DateTime.Now.AddDays(ageFrom);
all = item.Where(x => x.BirthDay > date).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not use a `List<Person>.FindAll()` method and pass in a method filter as the predicate?
You would use the method like this.

```
List<Person> filteredPersons = allPersons.FindAll(FilterPersons);
```

Below is the a sample method you would use as your filter.

```
bool FilterPersons(Person p)
{
    if(//enter criteria here to determine if you want to select the person)
        return true;
    else
        return false;
}
```

To do what you want this may be the code you need.

```
bool FilterPersons(Person p)
{
    var itemAge = Common.GetAge(item.BirthDay);

    if( itemAge > AgeFrom )
        return true;
    else
        return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you can apply filters on the result:

You can apply normal filters ( in `linq` expressions ) and than apply your functions on the result. Of course, you need to `refactor` your methods.

Something like this :

```
var result= Users.Where(s=>s.Name).ToList();
result= MyFilter(result);
```